# Linq to SQL One to Many query databind to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I've a LTSQL query which returns all users and userroles from SQL Server DB.
For example one user can have many user roles. So in the returned query if you look at a single user row it will have EntitySet(UserRole) for each userRole

The C# LTSQL query which returns all the the relational data is simply

```
   var results = from u in db.Users
             Select u;

   Gridview.DataSource = results;
   Gridview.Databind;
```

This displays all the data from the user table but not the userroles which is an entity in the results from the query.

If I want to display the user info from users table and all the userroles on a single gridView row, what is the most efficient approach? 
The gridView should look something like this:

```
UserId |  UserName  |  UserRoles         | 
1      | John Smith |  Admin, Accountant | Edit
2      | Dave Jones |  Sales, Admin      | Edit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var results = from u in db.Users
             Select new {
                           UserID = u.UsrID,
                           UserName = u.UserName,
                           UserRoles = string.Join(", ", u.UserRoles.Select(r => r.Name))
                        };
```